# Check for but allow duplicates entries in the Db

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My Db allows duplicate monuments, so the traditional method of checking for duplicates will not work. The user first inputs a monument name, then I run a check against the Db and if no duplicates found, great, allow the user to input the rest of the data. If one of more monuments with the same name are found, display a list of the monuments already in the Db. If this is truly a new monument with the same name, allow the user to input the new monument.

What I have so far:

```
         [Authorize]
      public ActionResult MonumentTitle(string battleRecordID, int callingRecordID)
      {
          ViewBag.monumentBattleRecID = battleRecordID; // ID of the battle
          ViewBag.battleName = getBattleName(battleRecordID);

          var vModel = new MonumentTitle();
          vModel.BattleRecID = ViewBag.monumentBattleRecID;
          vModel.BattleName = ViewBag.battleName;
          vModel.CallingRecID = callingRecordID;
          return View(vModel);

      }

      [HttpPost]
      [Authorize]
      public ActionResult MonumentTitle(MonumentTitle monumentTitle)
        {

            ViewBag.callingRecordID = monumentTitle.CallingRecID;
            ViewBag.battleName = monumentTitle.BattleName;
            ViewBag.MonumentName = monumentTitle.MonumentName;

            var NmonumentTitle = monumentTitle;
            ViewBag.battleName1 = NmonumentTitle.BattleName;
            var List_monument = from s in db.Monuments
                           where (s.MonumentStatus == "A" &&
                           s.MonumentBattleRecID == monumentTitle.BattleRecID &&
                           s.MonumentName == monumentTitle.MonumentName
                         )
                           select s;

            List_monument = List_monument.OrderBy(s => s.MonumentName);
            var vModel = new MonumentTitleDuplicate();
            vModel.MonumentTitle = NmonumentTitle;
            vModel.Monument = List_monument.ToList();


            if (vModel.Monument.Count == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("MonumentCreate", new { battleRecord = vModel.MonumentTitle.BattleRecID, callingRecordID = vModel.MonumentTitle.CallingRecID, monumentName = vModel.MonumentTitle.MonumentName });
            }
            {
                return RedirectToAction("MonumentTitleDuplicate",  vModel );
            }

        }
```

**Works for when there is not a duplicate. Where I run into a problem is trying to switch control to "MonumentTitleDuplicate" and pass the model.**

```
          [Authorize]
      [HttpGet]
      public ViewResult MonumentTitleDuplicate(MonumentTitleDuplicate monumentTitleDuplicate)
      {                  



          return View("MonumentTitleDuplicate", monumentTitleDuplicate);

      }

      [HttpPost]
      [Authorize]
      public ActionResult MonumentTitleDuplicate(MonumentTitle monumentTitle)
      {

          ViewBag.callingRecordID = monumentTitle.CallingRecID;
          return RedirectToAction("MonumentCreate", new { battleRecord = monumentTitle.BattleRecID, callingRecordID = monumentTitle.CallingRecID, monumentName = monumentTitle.MonumentName });

      }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult MonumentCreate(string battleRecord, int callingRecordID, string monumentName)
    {
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? What is happening?

Comment: trying to pass control to MonumentTitleDuplicate when the Monument Name is already on the Db.

Answer (score 0):

Got it -- needed to  use TempData to pass the model to the new controller so:

```
          [Authorize]
      public ActionResult MonumentTitle(string battleRecordID, int callingRecordID)
      {
          ViewBag.monumentBattleRecID = battleRecordID; // ID of the battle
          ViewBag.battleName = getBattleName(battleRecordID);

          var vModel = new MonumentTitle();
          vModel.BattleRecID = ViewBag.monumentBattleRecID;
          vModel.BattleName = ViewBag.battleName;
          vModel.CallingRecID = callingRecordID;
          return View(vModel);

      }

      [HttpPost]

      [Authorize]
      public ActionResult MonumentTitle(MonumentTitle monumentTitle)
        {

            ViewBag.callingRecordID = monumentTitle.CallingRecID;
            ViewBag.battleName = monumentTitle.BattleName;
            ViewBag.MonumentName = monumentTitle.MonumentName;

            var NmonumentTitle = monumentTitle;
            ViewBag.battleName1 = NmonumentTitle.BattleName;
            var List_monument = from s in db.Monuments
                           where (s.MonumentStatus == "A" &&
                           s.MonumentBattleRecID == monumentTitle.BattleRecID &&
                           s.MonumentName == monumentTitle.MonumentName
                         )
                           select s;

            List_monument = List_monument.OrderBy(s => s.MonumentName);
            var vModel = new MonumentTitleDuplicate();
            vModel.MonumentTitle = NmonumentTitle;
            vModel.Monument = List_monument.ToList();


            if (vModel.Monument.Count == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("MonumentCreate", new { battleRecord = vModel.MonumentTitle.BattleRecID, callingRecordID = vModel.MonumentTitle.CallingRecID, monumentName = vModel.MonumentTitle.MonumentName });
            }
            {
                TempData["monumentTitleDuplicate"] = vModel;
                return RedirectToAction("MonumentTitleDuplicate");
            }

        }


      [Authorize]
      public ActionResult MonumentTitleDuplicate()
      {

          MonumentTitleDuplicate monumentTitleDuplicate = TempData["MonumentTitleDuplicate"] as MonumentTitleDuplicate;

          return View(monumentTitleDuplicate);

      }

      [HttpPost]
      [Authorize]
      public ActionResult MonumentTitleDuplicate(MonumentTitle monumentTitle)
      {

          ViewBag.callingRecordID = monumentTitle.CallingRecID;
          return RedirectToAction("MonumentCreate", new { battleRecord = monumentTitle.BattleRecID, callingRecordID = monumentTitle.CallingRecID, monumentName = monumentTitle.MonumentName });

      }
```

Probably have some cleanup work to do (like getting rid of the stuff where I was trying to use ViewBag), but does appear to be working.